# Deleting item from list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Hello im trying to do simple python contact book and im trying to do add and delete function i succeeded in add but deleting was difficult any help please.

```
while True:
    choice = input("""
Type '1' to add Contact
Type '2' to delete contact
Type '3' to show all contacts
Type '4' to Enter Stiatical report menu 
Type 'exit' to exit          
       \n""") # Menu/options 

    def add(): # Function to add contact
        file = open("filename.txt", "a")
        name1 = input("Enter Contact Name\n").capitalize()
        number1 = input("Enter Contact Number\n")
        file.write(name1 + " " + number1 + "\n")
        file.close()

    def delete(): # Function to delete
        counter = 0
        index = 0
        deleted_contact = input("Enter the name you want to delete form the Contact list : ").capitalize() 
        with open("filename.txt", "r") as file:
            lines = file.readlines() 
            for files in lines:
                if files == deleted_contact:
                   index = counter
                else:
                    counter += 1
        del lines[index - 1]

    if choice == "1":
        add()
    elif choice == "2":
        delete()
```

Comment: Why did you not also write the lines to the file again after deleting one?

Comment: You are only deleting a line from your list (in memory), not in the file. Also not sure why you are subtracting 1 from index when you make the delete in the list ... that seems wrong. For instance, if the first line was the one you matched, `index` would be `0` and `index-1` would be negative 1, which would crash.

Comment: @topsail it wouldn't crash, negative indexes are valid in Python.  But it would delete something you didn't intend!

Comment: Include a description of what when wrong. What problem are we looking for?

Comment: @topsail index-1 as far as i know the index of list (lines = file.readlines() ) starts with 0 so the intended item will be 1 index less

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may separate the name and number on each line, then compare the name with the `deleted_contact`. If the name is the same, there's no need to write that line to a new list. The updated list of contacts should be used to overwrite the file.

```
def delete(): # Function to delete
    deleted_contact = input("Enter the name you want to delete from the Contact list: ").capitalize() 
    with open("filename.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines() 

    updated_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        name, _ = line.strip().split()
        if name != deleted_contact:
            updated_lines.append(line)

    with open("filename.txt", "w") as file:
        file.writelines(updated_lines)
```

Comment: i got that idea before and i did it but i get weired error says **number not accessed by Pylance** and i deleted it thinking its wrong code or something like this https://ibb.co/dQr0VC2

Comment: @momoshki The error message you're seeing is related to the `Pylance` extension in `VS Code`. You can get rid of `number` by replacing it with underscore: `name, _ = line.strip().split()`

Comment: Thanks you very much that worked out , but what the _ under score trick ? i didnt understood it

Comment: @momoshki You're welcome. [This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/5-different-meanings-of-underscore-in-python-3fafa6cd0379) discusses different meanings of underscore in `Python`. (Please check out the second item)

Answer (score 0):

you code `del lines[index - 1]` is only delete the item in list, the python list   is just in memory, you don't write in file, the change you need to save.

any other, i think you need to use [Pickle](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle), it can store your python Data structure into file even to reverse file to python Data structure, you can just focus how to chage the data in python not how to Sync the change with file.